# Is it possible to use `[Embed source=`... with Flash CS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, embed

Is it possible to do the following using AS3 and Flash CS3 IDE? The following only works if the `txt` TextField is created in the IDE and if the `txt.embedFonts` line is removed. This does not work if I create a TextField with AS3 instead of using the IDE. Is embedding a font via code only available in Flex?

```
package mtm.EmbedFonts
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.text.AntiAliasType;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class EmbedFonts extends MovieClip
    {
        public var txt:TextField; //References stage instance created in Flash CS3 IDE
        [Embed(source='C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/Arial.TTF', fontName='_Arial', unicodeRange='U+0020-U+002F,U+0030-U+0039,U+003A-U+0040,U+0041-U+005A,U+005B-U+0060,U+0061-U+007A,U+007B-U+007E')]
        protected var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();

        public function EmbedFonts():void
        {   
            initTextFormat();
            initTextField();
            txt.text = 'Hello World!';
        }

        protected function initTextFormat():void
        {
            format.letterSpacing = 1;
            format.size = 14;
            format.font = "Arial";
        }

        protected function initTextField():void
        {
            txt.multiline = true;
            txt.wordWrap = true;
            txt.border = true;
            txt.selectable = true;
            txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            txt.condenseWhite = true;
            txt.embedFonts = true;
            txt.setTextFormat(format);
            txt.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Embed] metatag is only available in Flex sadly.

Comment: correction; it is only available in the Flex Compiler. You can publish non-flex projects with that compiler, but the Flash IDE does uses a separate one.

Comment: That's unfortunate. If I had a deeper understanding of the reason, I would reply with something other than this: "Lame"